# How to add to my C# project SSH.NET Library?

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

I'm making a simple SSH Client and i've found SSH.NET Library but could you guys teach me how to add this library to my project? As i've downloaded it but i don't find any .ddl to add as reference to my project, if you could help me would be very great!

Thanks you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you've downloaded the source code. There are binaries as well:
https://sshnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/120565

I've been able to reference this dll: 
https://sshnet.codeplex.com/downloads/get/944155